# Passing URI/context path in Async thrift client

Tags: java, spring-boot, thrift

I am trying to build a Async thrift client. Below is the code I am building the same

```
TNonblockingTransport transport = new TNonblockingSocket("127.0.0.1", 8080);
TAsyncClientManager clientManager = new TAsyncClientManager();
TProtocolFactory protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
TCalculator.AsyncClient client = new TCalculator.AsyncClient(protocolFactory,clientManager,transport);
```

My Server is running on http://localhost:8080/calculator

Could you please help me out how to pass the uri here.

In case a sync client it's simple.

```
 TTransport transport;
  transport = new THttpClient("http://localhost:"+8080+"/calculator");
 transport.open();

Stacks used: Spring boot 2.2.1 & thrift.9
```

Or I am creating TNonblockingTransport wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have to use **TNonblockingSocket** to use transport in Non Blocking way. Change your transport definition to use **SocketChannel configuration** which will be like below:

**InetSocketAddress** will accept port and url for you:

```
 try (SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open()) {
        socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
        TNonblockingTransport transport = new TNonblockingSocket(socketChannel);
}

 final Asker.AsyncClient client = new Asker.AsyncClient(
                new TCompactProtocol.Factory(),
                new TAsyncClientManager(), transport);
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am not able to get any implementation of InetSocketAddress which takes URI in method.

Comment: code updated. why u need uri. isnt transeport sufficient

Comment: As mention server is running on localhost:8080/calculator. Hence for invoking handler need to pass URI .